# Can't Find Image After Download

Tags: android, image, download

I use this code to download an Image

```
public void buttonCondivisione(View view) {
    //onShareItem(view);
    String url = Utilities.removeString(mImages[POSITION_IMAGE].getLink());
    new DownloadImage().execute(url);
}

private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String TAG = "DownloadImage";
    private Bitmap downloadImageBitmap(String sUrl) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new URL(sUrl).openStream();   // Download Image from URL
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);       // Decode Bitmap
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception 1, Something went wrong!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadImageBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        saveImage(getApplicationContext(), result, "my_image.png");
    }
}

public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b, String imageName) {
    FileOutputStream foStream;
    try {
        foStream = context.openFileOutput(imageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, foStream);
        foStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, "FATTO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("6SENSE_APP Save Image", "Exception 2, Something went wrong!");
        Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, "No FATTO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But i can't find the image after the download. It's all ok because i see the Toast message after few seconds. I try different way to download my images but every method don't work for me. Stackoverflow is my last chance.

Comment: "i can't find the image after the download" -- how are you trying to "find the image"? You are storing that image on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for your app. On production hardware, nothing but your app has access to your app's portion of internal storage.

Comment: `context.openFileOutput(imageName`. That is private internal memory for your app. Other apps have no access. You did not tell how you tried to find your image but if you used a file explorer then you now know why you could not find it. Where did you look?

Comment: greenapps my goal is save the images in a way that they can use in other app like instagram